# grails 3 run-app fails due to file permissions set by perforce VCS

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.1

TLDR:

I have a Grails 3 project.  The run-app command was working fine.  Then I checked it into Perforce.  Now run-app fails.

---

DETAILS:

- Grails Version: 3.1.1
- Groovy Version: 2.4.5
- JVM Version: 1.8.0_91
- Gradle 2.13

% grails clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

% grails run-app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processResources'.

  > Could not copy file '/Volumes/Neo/singram/work/code/depot/dvdco/webapplications/nightcrawler/grails-app/i18n/messages.properties' to '/Volumes/Neo/singram/work/code/depot/dvdco/webapplications/nightcrawler/build/resources/main/messages.properties'.

---

GUESS at cause:

Perforce, when a file isn't checked out for editing, will make that file non-writable (chmod a-w).  As best I can tell, run-app invokes gradle's processResources which successfully copies the file in question once, then seemingly attempts to copy it *again during the same build cycle* and fails because thew newly copied file is not writable so it cannot be overwritten with a copy of itself.

---

WORK-AROUND

The run-app command succeeds if I check out the whole project for editing first.  Don't really want to have to do this as it introduces opportunity for error during check-ins.

---

QUESTION:

Is there a better way than my work-around?  Why is gradle's processResources copying the same files more than once?  Is there some sort of hook into processResources or run-app that I can use to "chmod -R u+w build" ?

Comment: Can you exclude the build folder from the Perforce repository? Those files are generated and therefore are not needed in a vcs.

Comment: A couple of options, methinks. Either 1) change the filetype(s) (if Perforce-controlled) to +w to make them writable; or 2) change the workspace spec to include the "allwrite" option to make all files writable.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, good suggestion, but I don't have the build folder in the repository.

Comment: @tkosinski thank you!  I didn't know about the "allwrite" option.  Fixed my problem.  Please enter this as an answer and I will accept it so you can get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options, methinks. Either 1) change the filetype(s) (if Perforce-controlled) to +w to make them writable; or 2) change the workspace spec to include the "allwrite" option to make all files writable. –

Comment: I went with option #2 and that solved my problem, thanks!  In the P4 UI, I set the option via workspace tab -> rightclick the workspace -> edit -> advanced -> set "allwrite" option